# Trigger on update of an attribute of a table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

There is a MySQL table called 'Coach' which has the following attributes.

```
coach_ID int
mileage_of_last_service_date double
mileage double
isAvailable boolean
```

isAvailable is set to 1 initially for all rows. I want to set a trigger which does the following.
When an update happens to mileage attribute and mileage gets greater than 100000, trigger must set the attributes for that particular of the same table as follows.

```
isAvailable = 0
mileage_of_last_service_date = mileage_of_last_service_date + mileage
mileage = 0
```

This is the query I've written.

```
create trigger set_availability_coach after update on coach 
for each row
when old.mileage > 10000 
begin 
update coach
set isAvailable = 0, mileage_of_last_service_date = mileage_of_last_service_date + old.mileage, mileage = 0
where coach.coach_ID = old.coach_ID;
end;
```

when I run this I get a syntax error in line 3.
Is there a fix for this?
Or any other way to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reformed this, this should be ok

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_availability_coach BEFORE UPDATE ON coach 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF OLD.mileage > 10000 THEN
    SET NEW.isAvailable = 0,
        NEW.mileage_of_last_service_date = OLD.mileage_of_last_service_date + NEW.mileage,
        NEW.mileage = 0;
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 7

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Comment: @maheshakya I've made an edit, however the code is typed freehand so I cannot promise it will compile.

Comment: This is MySQL syntax,right?
I'm using MySQL
There're some stuff which does not work in MySQL as I know. 
Could this be something like that?
I can't find any syntax errors in your piece of code though it give the same error as before.

Comment: IF OLD.mileage > 10000 THEN should be as IF NEW.mileage > 10000 THEN

Answer (score 0):

You can access `OLD` only at `BEFORE`-trigger, [see MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).
And you do not need `UPDATE ... SET ...` query, you can create `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, and modify `NEW` fields right in place.